# Django import error from django.db.models.expressions

Tags: python, django

When I try to get all my objects of a model, the following exception is raised:

```
    from django.db.models.expressions import OrderBy, Random, RawSQL, Ref
ImportError: cannot import name OrderBy
```

That's my input:

```
Page.objects.all() #Page is a model
```

And that's my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Answer(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    information_text = models.CharField(max_length=3000)

class Page(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    header = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    answers = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
```

What am I missing here? I'm new to Django.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: I use version 1.10.4

Comment: Where are you using the `OrderBy` in your code?

Comment: I'm not, that's why this is so unclear to me. Anyway, I ended up creating a new projects and making my models from scratch, and the exception is not thrown now.

Comment: And it's the exact same code?  It sounds like something was missing from the previous project then.  Either way, glad it's working for you now.

Comment: Yes, seems like it. When I created the first project, the django version that was in use was 1.6.x and I couldn't use `manage.py migrate/makemigrations`. Then I upgraded to 1.10.4 - maybe that broke something